# Primary reference could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, msbuild-task

I'm trying to setup an Azure pipeline to help build one of our solutions.

After resolving a number of issues due to package locations etc, I'm encountering the following error on build, which is failing the entire process:

```
##[warning]D:\a\1\s\website.metaproj(0,0): Warning MSB3268: The primary reference "D:\a\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Graph.Core.1.20.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Graph.Core.dll" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7".
```

I've tried to replicate this issue locally, in order to debug better, what's baffling is that the solution builds out absolutely fine in Visual Studio. However running MSBuild throws the same error.

I've exhausted all options I know of, checking package references, framework references etc and could do with some help pointing me in another direction.

Logic would tell me that the packages we're using are clashing the framework version 4.7, however, as stated this doesn't seem to be an issue in Visual Studio?

For reference we're calling the following packages:

```
  <package id="Microsoft.Graph" version="3.5.0" targetFramework="net47" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Graph.Core" version="1.20.1" targetFramework="net47" />
  <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net47" />
```

Comment: How did your solution on Visual Studio and MSBuild, are there any differences? Did you run `nuget restore`?

Comment: `Microsoft.Graph.Core` has `System.ValueTuple` version 4.3.0 dependency for `net45` platform, there is no version 4.0.1.0. Have you tried to check where does this version come from?

Comment: How about the issue? Did you find the reason of this issue?